# Compiling make based project with MSVC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

In OSX, I'm used to simply doing

```
./configure
make
```

But in MSVC when I do Project from existing code and try to compile I get hundreds of errors.

I'm trying to compile GLU from the Mesa3D library. How could I do this in MSVC? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still fighting with glu ? :)

In windows\VC8\mesa you have a .sln. Find it, open it, compile it, done.

Comment: Why is it that I say Static Release CRT and yet it outputs GLU32.DLL how can I just get 1 big lib?

Comment: right clic on glu -> project settings -> general -> change DLL to LIB

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the GLU library, but in the project settings, in the application type, you can select the type of the library (DLL or static library). Maybe for the target you mentioned, the output is a DLL and not a .LIB